# Warning: Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy! swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I need help with a UIWebView, so the user click "login" and it open a webpage to put the username and this code bellow is called to change the controller:

```
let tela = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabPrincipal") as! TabPrincipalViewController
                    tela.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                    self.present(tela, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Once I click to logout and use the same piece of code again, it says

> Warning: Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Anyone could please help me?

Comment: What does your logout code look like, i.e. what does it do to the main window's `rootViewController`?

Comment: Hello @NRitH, in the "LogoutViewController.swift" I'm doing a alert that if "yes" it display the login options page again if not, don't do anything.

This logout code is working for the others login options that I have... it is not working just for this one that I'm using the linkedin oauth2 opening a web page if the user don't have the app installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This for log Out button

self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Hello @Manvir Singh, in the "LogoutViewController.swift" I'm doing a alert that if "yes" it display the login options page again if not, don't do anything. This logout code is working for the others login options that I have... it is not working just for this one that I'm using the linkedin oauth2 opening a web page if the user don't have the app installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you present the view Controller, then use this dismiss view Controller code

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});

If you navigate the view Controller using navigation controller, then use this pop view Controller code

self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true);